# Does app store filter out NFC apps for iPhones which do not have NFC?

Tags: ios-appstore, nfc

I'm developing an iOS app based on NFC technology.

As I learn, NFC card read support has been introduced pretty recently and older iPhone models (iPhone 8 and below I guess) don't have it.

So when my app goes live on the app store, will the app be displayed for people having older iPhones?
Will they be shown a message like "this app is not supported on your iPhone" or will they have to face post-installation frustration?

Comment: NFC (as in Apple Pay etc) works in the 6S, which is the oldest phone that can run iOS 14. idk if that actually answers your question.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for your response!
ALthough Apple Way works since long, my app is meant for reading and writing NFC tags, support to which has been introduced pretty recently. That's what I'm wondering about.